# Lista concatenada de valores em PHP

Tags: php, array, formulário, post, foreach

Estou tentando criar uma lista concatenada dos nomes de clientes utilizando apenas uma entrada em php, mas por fim, o resultado não foi o que eu esperava.

Parte Externa (Interface):

No início, a cada nome inserido no `input`, o usuário decide se quer adicionar mais um nome ou já exibir a lista com os nomes já inseridos por dois botões chamados com os nomes `add (+)` e `show (Exibir)` respectivamente. Desta forma, a cada botão `add (+)` clicado, o sistema irá imprimir mais uma nova entrada vazia abaixo da preenchida para colocar mais um nome, e outro nome, e outro e assim sucessivamente até o usuário cadastrar todos os nomes necessários e resolver imprimir uma lista de todos os clientes que foram cadastrados no sistema ao pressionar o botão `Enviar`.

Parte Interna (código de processamento):

1º) Neste sistema terá um contador chamado `$i` que irá controlar a quantidade de nomes que serão cadastrados na lista, o que também irá definir o número de linhas que a coluna irá ter;
2º) Criei um array chamado `$nome` para armazenar todos os nomes que o usuário cadastrar;
3º) Criei uma nova variável chamada `$conteudo` que irá armazenar todos os nomes que o usuário for inserindo de forma concatenada;
4º) Foi criada uma função chamada `get_post_action` que tem como parâmetro a variável `$nome`, que irá retornar os nomes de todos os botões existentes no formulário;
5º) Criei um `switch-case` para definir as ações distintas dos botões `add` e `show`;

> De que forma seria possível criar uma lista concatenada de nomes com as linhas inseridas através de inputs funcionando em PHP?

```js
<?php
 $i = 0;
 $nome = array("", "", "", "", "", "");
 $conteudo = "";
 function get_post_action($name){
  $params = func_get_args();
  foreach ($params as $name) {
   if (isset($_POST[$name])) {
    return $name;
   }
  }
 }
 switch (get_post_action('add', 'show')) {
  case 'add':
   $i++;
   $nome[$i] = $_POST['nome'];
   $conteudo += "$nome[$i]<br>";
   echo "<input type='text' name='nome'><input type='submit' value='+' name='add'><hr>";
  break;
  case 'show':
   echo "$nome";
  break;
  default:
   $conteudo = "";
  break;
 } 

?>
```

```html
<form action="teste.php" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="nome">
 <input type="submit" value="+" name="add"><hr>
 <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="show">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa ajustar no seu código 2 coisas:

- Arrumar uma forma de persistir os dados dados do formulário após o submit para poder recuperá-los depois. Sugiro fazer isso com sessão.
- Informar para o PHP que o seu campo "nome" é um array de nomes e você consegue fazer isso alterando o attributo `name` do input de `name="nome"` para `name="nome[]"` (no exemplo abaixo eu coloquei no plural somente para ficar mais semântico).

O código final do arquivo `teste.php` ficou da seguinte forma:

```php
<?php
// inicia a sessao para guardar os nomes
session_start();

/**
 * Quando a pagina carregar
 * Iniciaremos um array vazio na sessão
 * somente caso ele não exista na sessão
 * por exemplo na primeira vez que a página carrega
 */
$_SESSION['nomes'] = $_SESSION['nomes']?: array();

/**
 * Aqui salvaremos os nomes enviados do
 * formulário somente se a ação for para add (+)
 */
if (isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao'] == '+') {
    $_SESSION['nomes'] = $_POST['nomes'];
}

/**
 * Esta função percorre todos os nomes
 * salvos na sessão e imprime um campo de texto
 * com o nome já preenchido
 */
function print_campos () {
    foreach ($_SESSION['nomes'] as $nome) {
        echo '<input type="text" name="nomes[]" value="'.$nome.'" /><br />';
    }
}

/**
 * Gera a lista concatenada de nomes
 * somente se a ação for "Enviar" (show)
 */
if (isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao'] == 'Enviar') {
    $lista_concatenada = sprintf('%s', implode('<br />', $_SESSION['nomes']));
    echo $lista_concatenada;
}
?>

<form action="teste.php" method="POST">
    <?php print_campos() ?>
    <input type="text" name="nomes[]" />
    <input type="submit" value="+" name="acao"><hr>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="acao">
</form>
```

**Sugestões de leitura**

- [Sessões](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.session.php) em específico o [exemplo básico](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/session.examples.basic.php)
- Manipulação de [arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.array.php) no exemplo usei a função [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php)
- Manipulação de [strings](https://www.php.net/ref.strings) no exemplo foi utilizado a função [sprintf()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: Funcionou certinho @Vinicius.Silva. Valeu pela orientação! ;-) Agora eu só vou fazer alguns ajustes para adicionar mais um botão para remover linha por linha, pra quando toda vez que eu for atualizar o script em PHP não ficar aqueles exageros de linhas. Gratidão! :-D